# non-trivial rvalue and lvalue example

Tags: c++, lvalue-to-rvalue

I am not sure about some rvalue/lvalue non-trvial examples.

are `std::vector<int>({1,2,3})[0]` and `std::vector<int>()` expressions below lvalue or rvalue?

the code has no actual usage but it surprises me a bit that the code is valid. It looks like they are both lvalues. or not?

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>({1,2,3})[0] = 0;
    std::vector<int>() = {1,2,3}; 
    return 0;
}
```

further example...

The `std::vector<int>()` expression below is a rvalue. right?
and how about the expression `std::vector<int>({1,2,3})[0]`?
Both the vector object from `std::vector<int>()` and the int value from `...[0]` are temporary values. right?

```
auto v = std::vector<int>();
int i = std::vector<int>({1,2,3})[0];
```

Comment: Dan Saks has a good piece on this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mK0r21-djk8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector<int>()` is an rvalue, because the syntax `type()` always produces an rvalue. `std::vector<int>() = {1,2,3};` is allowed because assigning to rvalues of class type is allowed in general, but can be disabled for a specific class by defining `operator=` with a [`&` qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions), which `std::vector` doesn't do.

`std::vector<int>({1,2,3})[0]` is an lvalue, because [`std::vector<...>::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) is defined to return an lvalue reference. It's possible to define it to return rvalue or lvalue depending on whether the vector it's called on an rvalue or lvalue (see the link above), but `std::vector` doesn't do that.

> Both the vector object from std::vector() and the int value from ...[0] are temporary values. right?

The `vector` - yes. The `int` - no, at least formally.

Whether or not something an object is a temporary depends solely on the way it was created, e.g. `type()` will always give you a temporary.

The vector allocates its elements on the heap, which results in normal, non-temporary objects. It doesn't matter that the vector itself is a temporary.

Comment: Could the `std::vector` be changed to disallow being modified as an rvalue?  Or does the standard require that it have its current behavior, so the standard would have to be amended if that behavior were to be modified.

Comment: @Eljay The standard requires the current behavior. If you were writing a custom vector, you could do that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat great explanation. And a follow-up question. While `auto& i = std::vector<int>();` is invalid,  `auto& i = std::vector<int>(1)[0];` is valid to compile because the `..[0]` is not a temp. right? is it an undefined behaviour? how about the lifetime of the int from `...[0]`?

Comment: @rnd_nr_gen It will compile and isn't UB per se, but any access to the reference after that will cause UB, because it immediately becomes dangling.

Comment: ...because the vector, being a temporary, is destroyed at the end of the full expression (here it means at the `;`), and it takes its elements with it. Also, a minor detail, but the element not being a temporary doesn't directly make this line valid. What makes it valid is that `...[0]` returns an lvalue. (The difference matters, because in some cases you can end up with an rvalue referring to a non-temporary (e.g. if you do `std::move`), or an lvalue referring to a temporary (e.g. if you have `int &foo(int &&x){return x;}`, and then call `foo(42)`).)